# How can I use "git status" to see only certain type of files?

Tags: git, git-status

When I use 'git status', it shows me all the modified files. But I wish to see only files with a certain extension (like .py) which I will commit. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to match all files anywhere in the tree that match `*.py`, then use the following:

```bash
git status "*.py"
```

This ensures that the shell doesn't expand the path and it's interpreted by Git as a pathspec.  You can also use single quotes under a Unix shell, but not under Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You could run:

```
git status | grep .py
```

Comment: Thanks. It will show all the files with "py" in it.

Comment: but not on Windows

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans windows has WSL now, so it's finally on par with other operating systems.

Comment: No. Using WSL is just as much "not using Windows" as using cygwin/msys bash. or virtualbox or docker with host filesystem access.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok, do you have a furher point with this? Or just being pedantic

Comment: I was looking for this as a Windows user, so the point was "this doesn't work on Windows", for other Windows users who find this answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so for any future readers on Windows: install WSL. For you: perhaps you can try compiling grep yourself or perhaps it's part of 'git bash' which i think comes with git for windows?

Comment: WSL has the same isolated file system problem that any other VM has, so instead, the better solution is the other answer that shows that you don't even need grep, on any OS: pattern matching is apparently built into `git status` already.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, let's not forget the basic `--` which has the same behaviour for most git commands.

```
git status -- *.py
```

as hinted at by `git help status`

> `git status [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...`

Answer (score 0):

If you're scripting this, use the core commands.  They're faster, because they don't go gathering and prettifying extra info for human convenience, plus you don't have to scrape the extra bits off to get at what you want.

```
git diff-index --name-only @ -- \*.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Found it on [this page](https://gist.github.com/chrismccoy/8775224), it has a lot of great shortcuts for git tasks.

A little more complicated than the other answers, but it works.

`git status -s | grep -o ' \S*YOUR_FILE_TYPE$'`

For Python files it would be:

`git status -s | grep -o ' \S*py$'`